# DraftJS triggers content change on focus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I have an editor on a page and `save` button. I want `save` button only to appear if there are changes (since last save). So, when you save, i set `this.setState({hasChanges: false})` and in `onChange` function i set `hasChanges` to `true`.

And that's all working fine. The issue is that editor will fire `onChange` event when editor gain focus (but content is not changed yet). And, that is expected behaviour according to their [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-managing-focus.html)

> The event listeners within the component will observe focus changes
>   and propagate them through onChange as expected, so state and DOM will
>   remain correctly in sync.

Is there some way to know if content has changed inside `onChange` method, or only selection is changed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I posted this answer to your question on github earlier today, but I'll add it here as well for future reference:

You're right in that onChange is called every time the `editorState` changes. And since the `editorState` holds both the `selectionState` and the `contentState`, it will change both when there's a content edit, and when the selection/focus changes.

If you want to know if the change that triggered the `onChange` method was in the `contentState` or in the `selectionState`, you could compare them with their old values:

```
function onChange(newState) {
  const currentContentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()
  const newContentState = newState.getCurrentContent()

  if (currentContentState !== newContentState) {
    // There was a change in the content  
  } else {
    // The change was triggered by a change in focus/selection
  }
}
```

Now, if you know that the change was in the `contentState`, you can get some more info by calling [newState.getLastChangeType()](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-editor-state.html#lastchangetype). It should return any of [these values](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/docs/APIReference-EditorChangeType.md#values) (unless you, or some plugin you've added, have created new change types).

Comment: This test is invalid, for example when using insertDataBlock() the equality remains true, while the content HAS actually changed. You should deep-compoare the objects.

Comment: This doesn't detect some style changes done by toolbar

Answer (score 2):

However, sometimes just the conditional  `if (currentContentState !== newContentState)` not work and not detect the change for cases like when you to modify the content state using `Entity.mergeData` together with `forceSelection` because this change is stored inside entity and is not exposed in `contentState`.

So you could do something like that additionaly.

```
this.currentEntityMap = null;

function onChange(newEditorState) {

 const currentContentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
 const newContentState = newEditorState.getCurrentContent();
 const newContentStateRaw = convertToRaw(newContentState);
 const newEntityMap = newContentStateRaw ? newContentStateRaw.entityMap : null;

//so if you have the two entity maps, you can to compare it, here an example function.
 const isEntityMapChanged = this.isEntityMapChanged(newEntityMap);

 this.currentEntityMap = newEntityMap;  
}

 isEntityMapChanged(newEntityMap) {
        let isChanged = false;
        if (this.currentEntityMap) {
            loop1:
            for (const index of Object.keys(newEntityMap)) {
                if (this.currentEntityMap[index] && newEntityMap[index].type === this.currentEntityMap[index].type) {
                    loop2:
                    for (const prop of Object.keys(newEntityMap[index].data)) {
                        if (newEntityMap[index].data[prop] !== this.currentEntityMap[index].data[prop]) {
                            isChanged = true;
                            break loop1;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    isChanged = true;
                    break loop1;
                }
            }
        }

        return isChanged;
    }
```

then to used the flag `isEntityMapChanged` and the first conditional for to do the save.

Answer (score 1):

you should use code follow:

```
  const onChange = newState => {
    if (
      // when content change or line style change will change the state
      !newState.getCurrentContent().equals(editorState.getCurrentContent()) ||
      !newState
        .getCurrentInlineStyle()
        .equals(editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle())
    ) {
      setEditorState(newState);
    }
  };
```

if you just use content equal ,then line style change will not on effect.